# FirebaseStorage An unknown error occurred. Please refresh the page and try again

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I lost contact with `Firebase Storage` through my app.

I tried to visit Firebase Storage page to try to find out what happened and found the following

[image]

Everything was fine but everything happened suddenly.

I tried creating a new project from the same account, same browser, and same connection, and everything seems fine with the new project.

When I imagine that my application has been officially published and this suddenly happens to users, this is very embarrassing
Is there a general defect? Or is something happening to me?

Comment: If you're having a problem in the Firebase console, you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/) directly. This isn't something the volunteers of Stack Overflow can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @DougStevenson's comment, here are some of the suggestions I could recommend:

- Install the latest Firebase version which is `10.5.2` as of writing. You may refer to this [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) for more information.
- You may also file an issue through this [Github link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues).

Comment: i already  have the latest version .. The horror here that the issue solved its self suddenly  O_O

Comment: Sometimes Google provides gradual updates to its systems, we encounter errors such as this. Glad this has been resolved.